# NicEdit upload on your own server

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, nicedit

i have problem with uploading on my own server with nicEdit wysiwyg editor.

When you clikc on upload image you will upload image on other site. Here: imgur dot com

This is it: http://nicedit.com/demos.php

I want to use them php script to upload image on my own server/domain.
Can somebody tell me how to do it?

Here is the script: http://svn.nicedit.com//trunk/nicUpload/php/nicUpload.php

Still show message "Failed to upload image".

In console on firebug show this one:

```
<script>
        try {
            top.nicUploadButton.statusCb({"error":"Invalid Upload ID"});
        } catch(e) { alert(e.message); }

</script>
```

POST is okay but i dont understand this. :(

Have anybody som good answer for me?

Thank you very buch.
PS: sorry for my english. :)

Daniel.

Comment: Can you prepare an example page that uploads to your server? Is the image uploaded and stored on your server, despite getting error message? There are currently too many questions, so answering is really difficult. When we get the example page, we can then check HTTP responses, which may give more information.

Comment: If u get nicEdit.js at the end is init upload sections with imgur.com - modify Ur nicEdit.js for set Ur site's url (var nicUploadButton=nicEditorAdvancedButton.extend({nicURI:"http://api.imgur.com/2/upload.json"...)

Comment: You can find the example on this page: http://nicedit.danielhutnan.com/.

I'm uploading it to upload/.

Thanks for any answer. :)

Daniel.

Comment: @Sergey I'm trying this but it doesn't work. :-/

Answer (score 0):

Did you install the PHP APC library on your server? I think you need to generate this id.
`$id = $_POST['APC_UPLOAD_PROGRESS'];`

Answer (score 0):

NicEditor uses imgur as the default image upload service. The source code follows the API format described here: http://api.imgur.com/resources_anon#upload

My suggestion would be to implement the API request and response defined there.

Comment: Be careful when posting copy and paste boilerplate/verbatim answers to multiple questions, these tend to be flagged as "spammy" by the community. If you're doing this then it usually means the questions are duplicates so flag them as such instead: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12886113/419